# Phonegap duplicating contact

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm using apache cordova but seems not working with phonenumber. Can someone help me ? it's duplicating numbers in listview.

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
         document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
                var options = new ContactFindOptions();
                 options.filter="";
                 options.multiple=true; 
                 var fields = ["*"];
                 navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
    }
    function onSuccess(contacts) 
    {
         for(var i=0;i<contacts.length;i++)
         {
              if(contacts[i].phoneNumbers)
              {
                for (var j = 0; j < contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++) 
                {   
                      $('#contactList').append("<li><a href='#'><h2>"+ contacts[i].displayName +"</h2><p>" + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value + "</p></a></li>");                  
                }
              }
        }
        $('#contactList').listview("refresh");

    }
    function onError(contactError) {
        alert('onError!');
    }
</script>
```

How to prevent from duplicating contact! ?

Comment: please add the part where the function is called. I assume its called twice

Comment: @MaxBumaye : I have posted the whole code. Thanks!